# Why do Docker image links contain multiple versions and labels?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

Hope this isn't a stupid question. When looking at Docker images, particularly from the official repository they list multiple versions and labels for each dockerfile. For instance:

```
9.1.6-php8.0-apache-buster, 9.1-php8.0-apache-buster, 9-php8.0-apache-buster, php8.0-apache-
buster, 9.1.6-php8.0-apache, 9.1-php8.0-apache, 9-php8.0-apache, php8.0-apache, 9.1.6-apache-
buster, 9.1-apache-buster, 9-apache-buster, apache-buster, 9.1.6-apache, 9.1-apache, 
9-apache, apache, 9.1.6, 9.1, 9, latest, 9.1.6-php8.0, 9.1-php8.0, 9-php8.0, php8.0
```

My question is why do they list so many variations of the version in the link (i.e. 9.1.6-php8.0-apache-buster and 9.1-php8.0-apache-buster, etc.)? I'm not sure if this is for searching and spiders (though it wouldn't need to be included in the link like they do), or if it is because each dockerfile can be modified to any of those versions? (and if so, how?). For instance, the above drupal dockerfile supports 9 - 9.1.6 and the dockerfile can be adjusted to  that version. TBH, it's mainly just confusing why they do their links like that if its just for search indexing because it looks like its supporting multiple versions of something.

Answer (score 0):

Today, these tags may all point to the same image. However tomorrow, 9.1.7 may be released, and when that happens, all the 9.1.6 images will remain unchanged and a new set of 9.1.7 images are built with generic tags like 9.1 and 9. Additionally when 9.2.0 is released, or php 8.1 comes out, or the next version of debian is released, any of these could be breaking changes for an app. So in your Dockerfile, you might say:

```
FROM ${BASE}:9.1-php8.0-apache-buster
```

And by doing so, you'll get the 9.1.7 when it's released, but not 9.2.0, and you won't accidentally be shifted over to nginx, or upgraded from buster to bullseye when it becomes stable. The more change your app is able to tolerate, the more generic you may be in your base image tag. The risk being one of those changes may break your app.

You can be very specific and pin to an exact base image that doesn't automatically update, but then as security vulnerabilities are patched in newer base images, your child image would remain vulnerable since it's locked to an old base image that won't receive updates.

Comment: So those tags in the links can be used in the FROM statement, and act as a wildcard: i.e. 9.1 == 9.1.X? So this means it can install anything from 9.0 to <9.2? If so, then why is there 9.0.11 below it? Sorry, it's still a little confusing how their method is working.

Comment: @user58446 This would be a easier to give specifics if I knew which repo you were looking at.

Comment: There's not one in particular i'm looking to find, just trying to understand why it is done this way. When i do go to look for one though, I always wonder why don't they just say `9.16-php8.0-apache-buster` instead of adding all the extra? Why is `9.1-php8.0-apache-buster` or just `9.1` necessary? What does it do, and how would I use it?

Comment: @user58446 you're asking a question about a specific 9.0.11 tag on some repo. Are you saying that tag points to the same image as the 9.1.x tags? I can't see your screen to give you a better answer.

Comment: where did 9.0.11 tag come from? you mean 9.1.6? Are you saying there isn't a pattern here regardless of the repo? Look at [rust](https://hub.docker.com/_/rust/) or [gcc](https://hub.docker.com/_/gcc/)... for gcc, it says `10.3.0, 10.3, 10, latest`, so is the 'latest' image 10.3 or 10.0? I'm guessing 10.3 obviously, but the mystery is why bother putting 10.0 in the link at all.

Comment: @user58446 The 9.0.11 came from your comment above, but I don't know what you're looking to tell you more about it. If you look at gcc, click on the tags, you'll see that 10.3.0, 10.3, and 10 all point to the same digest today. Over a week ago, the 10 tag was the same as 10.2 and 10.2.0. If there was a 10.2.1, then 10.2 would be updated to be something different than 10.2.0. This is how they provide a rough approximation of semver with docker tags.